# Laravel 5 Error occurs while inserting into sql table with sequence_id

Tags: php, laravel-5, auto-increment

I am trying to insert data to oracle sql and nothing happened but this error message

> Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: invalid number Position :
>   162 Statement : insert into SLS_test (call_id, phone_number,
>   operator_name, call_comment, complaint, spon_id, technical, served,
>   serve_comment, call_time, serve_time) values (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4,
>   :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9, :p10) Bindings :
>   [call_id_seq.nextval,call_id_seq.nextval,996,996,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,0,0,0,0,asd,asd,2018-07-31
>   16:09:09,2018-07-31 16:09:09,2018-07-31 16:09:09,2018-07-31 16:09:09]

---

My WelcomeController.php :

```
public function create(Request $req)
{
    $phone_number = $req -> input('phone_number');
    $operator_name = $req -> input('operator_name');
    $call_comment = $req -> input('call_comment');
    $complaint = $req -> input('complaint');
    $spon_id = $req -> input('spon_id');
    $technical = $req -> input('technical');
    $served = $req -> input('served');
    $serve_comment = $req -> input('serve_comment');
    $ctime = new DateTime();
    $stime = new DateTime();
    $data = array("call_id" => "call_id_seq.nextval" , "phone_number"=>$phone_number,"operator_name"=>$operator_name,"call_comment"=>$call_comment,"complaint"=>$complaint,"spon_id"=>$spon_id,"technical"=>$technical,"served"=>$served,"serve_comment"=>$serve_comment,"call_time"=>$ctime,"serve_time"=>$stime);
    DB::table('test')->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: Seems like the bindings are happening twice. Or at least the bindings shows each value twice.

Comment: first of all i'm unable to understand why are you doing these much when you can do it in just max 2 lines.

Comment: @Ashish cost much time on it and can't find an easy solution. Code works fine without call_id_seq which is i defined oracle sequence also I am new to laravel.

Comment: @Б.Ертөнц learn eloquent first. as of now. you already have the same values in your request. so you don't need to declare a new variable. moreover, you can merge extra record to request like `$req->merge(['key'=>value,'anotherkey'=>value])` and then use insert query as you have used. `DB::table('test')->insert($req->all())`

Comment: @Ashish appreciate for your advice :-))